# Big Data Retrieval and Processing Python and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, performance, postgresql

Just for some background. I am developing a hotel data analytics dashboard much like this one [here](https://my.infocaptor.com/free_data_visualization.php"D3 Builder") using d3.js and dc.js (with cross filter). It is a Django project and the database I am using is Postgresql. I am currently working on a universal bar graph series, it will eventually allow the user to choose the fields (from the data set provided) that they would like to see plotted against each other in a bar chart format.

My database consists of 10 million entries, with 54 fields each (single table). Retrieving the three fields used to plot the time based bar chart takes over a minute. Processing the data in Python(altering column key names to match those of the universal bar chart) and putting the data into a json format to be used by the graph takes a further few minutes which is unacceptable for my desired application.

Would it be possible to "parallelise" the querying of the data base and would this be faster than what I am doing currently (a normal query). I have looked around a bit and not found much. And is there a library or optimized function I might use to parse my data to the desired format quickly?

Comment: Isn't that an option to use the json file straight from the beginning, instead of building it from the database?

Comment: @YannisP I thought about doing that, I did try something of the sort but perhaps I should try that again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on similar kind of table size. Well, for what you are looking for you need to switch to something like a distributed postgres environment i.e. Greenplum which is MPP architecture and supports columnar storage. Which is ideal for table with large number of columns and table size.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_columnar_storage_disk_mem_mgmnt.html

If you do not intend to switch to Greenplum you can try table partitioning in your current postgres database. Your dashboard queries should be such that they query individual partitions, that way you end up querying smaller partitions(tables) and the query time will be much much faster.